# Remove "[ ]" and all that occurences within in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm building a small text clean up program and I'm currently testing it on Wiki articles,and I'm trying to efficiently remove the "[2]", "[14]", "[nb 6]" etc.

I have this code which nearly does the job, but its seem very overly long and I feel there must be a way to do it in one line, but I'm new to Regex and can't figure it out. Also I've read mixed opinions on Regex so if theres an alternsate way that'd be great.

Anyway here is my current code:

```
string  refinedText = Regex.Replace(sourceText, @"\[[0-9]\]", "");

        refinedText = Regex.Replace(refinedText, @"\[[0-9]", "");
        refinedText = Regex.Replace(refinedText, @"\[[a-z]", "");
        refinedText = Regex.Replace(refinedText, @"[0-9]\]", "");
```

The issue is there are 2 numbers within the "[ ]" and I don't know how to tell it to remove both, as doing "0-9" just removes the first number, I can do the replace in 2 parts for them; but for the instances of "[nb 3]" the b always remains as there no way I can specify the lone "b" after the "[ ]" are gone to be used as the reference. Also "[nb 14]" same issue with if there are double digits after the "nb".

I'm sure this is simply to do in 1 line, but I can't find any where explaining regex to this extent.

-Thanks.

Comment: ? `\[[^\[\]]+\]` or `\[[^\]]*\]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to delete the square brackets along with their content, no matter what that content is, the expression looks like this:

```
@"\[[^\]]*\]"
```

This means "match everything until you get to the closing bracket". This is more efficient than the dot with reluctant qualifier `.*?` because it avoids so-called [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Great thank you, I knew it'd be simple, I'd seen the ^ used in other examples but wasn't entirely sure of its function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+` modifier:

```
string refinedText = Regex.Replace(sourceText, @"\[[0-9]+\]", "");
```

As the [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains:

> Matches the previous element one or more times.

To remove any characters between the brackets:

```
string refinedText = Regex.Replace("[0as9]", @"\[.+\]", "");
```

Or if you want to also handle the `"[]"` case, then change `+` to `*`:

> Matches the previous element zero or more times.

```
string refinedText = Regex.Replace("[0as9]", @"\[.*\]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string  refinedText = Regex.Replace(sourceText, @"\[[0-9]+\]", "");
```

Also you may try like this:

```
var refinedText = Regex.Replace(sourceText, @" ?\[.*?\]", string.Empty);
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fZ4vJ2/1)**

This will remove everything inside the text box including characters and numbers